Material makes one side of the object go black no matter how I turn it
When I use this material one of the sides of the mesh turns black. When I turn the object the side that was black aquires color but the one that replaces it goes black. Other materials work fine, but this one doesn't for some reason.
Object from one side:

The same object from the other side (camera position doesn't change):

Shaders:


Hello, are you sure that you're using the Bevel node correctly? It is supposed to be plugged into the Normal input

@moonboots If I plug it in the Normal output the mesh is just white. I am following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/EQ149bMtKRA?si=oRF-qejyVzHbhLsU

You should have put the information about the tutorial in the question, because otherwise nobody knows what you tried to create there since this is not the "intended" way to use the Bevel node. Anyway I guess my answer should provide some information to get it to work.

Sorry to say that, but you have to pay closer attention to the tutorial (and I do not consider it a beginner tutorial since he does not explain each step). First of all, the result of the Mix Color node is not plugged into the Base Color of the Principled BSDF - it is plugged directly into the Material Output node to preview it.
But there are things he does explain: the Radius on both of your Bevel nodes are the same - he sets the second one with the lower Sample number to a radius of 0. Then your Mix Color node is set to Mix, he sets it to Difference. Apart from all that it would still look incorrect, because you are in Material Preview mode in the viewport, while he is in Render mode. The Material Preview uses EEVEE, but the Bevel node only works in Cycles.

The bevel node works by finding the face normals of your mesh and interpolating between in sharp corners. Normals are just vectors that point directly away from the surface of your mesh. Vectors are commonly represented as RGB values. Which is the color you're seeing on your mesh.

This is just on the "all-positive" side of your mesh. Vectors can point in negative directions. But all colors can only be represented by 0 or positive values. The black is just you seeing a negative vector.

You can tell this because the colors come back when you run this into an "Absolute" node to get only positive numbers.

The bevel node is not meant to change the color of your mesh. Make sure it's plugged into the normal output. If you're not getting the beveled edge effect try increasing the radius or making sure your scale is applied with Ctrl+A.

The Bevel node in the tutorial is used to create edge wear, and even though it is not "meant" to change the color, it can be used as that - although in the tutorial this is only used as preview to show the output and then later used as mask. So what you explain here is the "standard" use maybe, but has nothing to do with the tutorial and is not the issue Chapotle is facing here.

Well his question is asking why the bevel node makes certain faces black no matter which way you turn it. This definitely answers that. But yeah I didn't watch the tutorial he was referring to. Ain't got time for that. Lmao.

I know the tutorial  His main problem is that even when he sets everything up like in the tutorial it will still show black, because he is in Material Preview and the Bevel node is a Cycles only node, with Eevee it will give either no or incorrect results, which is not mentioned in your answer.
